# What is the precise definition of the prefix "co" in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Given a notion "A" in mathematics, in many cases "coA" is also defined. Here are some common examples:

1. sine and cosine;
2. tangent and cotangent;
3. secant and cosecant;
4. function and cofunction;
5. morphism and comorphism;
6. functor and cofunctor;
7. domain and codomain;
8. limit and colimit;
9. set and coset;
10. product and coproduct;
11. fibration and cofibration;
12. homology and cohomology;
13. homotopy and cohomotopy;
14. prime and coprime;
15. vector and covector;

and the list goes on. My question is, what is the generally accepted meaning of the prefix "co"? Given a mathematical notion "A", when is "coA"
also defined? Also, is "cocoA" always the same as "A"? (Here I am only asking about mathematical terminologies, so "coconut" does not count.)

**Edit**: Among all the examples listed above, the pair puzzles me the most is "set and coset". A coset is defined in the context of a subgroup of a group. I am wondering if there is any reason to call it a **co**set.

Comment: See [cosine : etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cosine#Etymology).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, does this only apply to trigonometric functions?

Comment: In most cases it's from the latin prefix _'com-'_, which means (usually) "together with". In the case of the trig functions it comes from the more specific latin _'complement'_ meaning it applies to another (complementary) side of the triangle.

Comment: Yes; I think that the moden ones are named so by analogy, to connote a couple of "complementar" concepts.

Comment: *"A comathematician is a device for turning cotheorems into ffee."* Some comathematician, I don't know . . .

Comment: +1 for the "coconut" non-example/

Comment: I can give at least one example where "cocoX" is not the same as "X": if A is a cofinite subset of X (i.e. we taking "A = coX"), then B = X - A is a finite subset of X. Taking "cocoX" means we're looking for a subset of A such that its complement in A is finite. If $B \neq \emptyset$, then $|A| < |X|$ and clearly “cocoX” cannot be X.

Comment: To me, the prefix $co$ means $with$, $together$ or $complimentary$ as told by numerous [sources of definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=co+prefix+definition&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS755US755&oq=co+prefix+de&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i60.14657j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: In category theory coX is obtained by reversing all the arrows in the definition of X. (limit colimit is an example)

Comment: @ensbana, according to your definition, a set is cocofinite iff it is finite, right?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to interpret the notion of a "cocofinite set". I think the reason why this is confusing, and also why "coco" is not the negation of "co", is because the notion of inclusion is implied in the definition of "cofinite set". If you say "A is a confinite subset of X" and "C is a cofinite subset of A", then we have $C \subset A \subset X$ (and hence except the special case I mentioned above, "coco" does not negate "co"). I think the negation happens when "co" is used roughly in the sense of "dual" (like "dual of a dual is primal", in the context of linear programming).

Comment: This is the definition of cofinite subset that I used, by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness

Comment: @ensbana, how about defining a set to be cocofinite iff its complement is cofinite?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find a definition of "cocofiniteness" so that "cocofiniteX" is the same as "X"? Anyway, I don't think we can just say "a set A is cocofinite iff...", but rather the definition must be formulated as "A is a cocofinite subset of a set X iff...", since the inclusion relation must be made explicitly clear.

Comment: It's sort of like how saying "A is related iff..." wouldn't make sense, but we have to say "A is related to X iff...".

Comment: @ensbana I think there's only one way to interpret cocofinite, and that is a the complement being cofinite.

Comment: Co- means dual, in Category theory you usually always get a theorem, then its dual by reversing all appropriate arrows.    Cosine / Sine I think are unrelated to this phenomenon.  The duality principle is really powerful.  You can either write out the second proof in the dual setting, or just say by duality we have this other theorem.  For example the contra/covariant Yoneda lemmas.  You only need to prove one: contravarient functor case or covariant functor case.  Though when starting out, you should prove both for practice.  Only once you're familiar with how the duality works should you skp

Comment: I don't get the point of this question. In most of these cases, "co" is being used in a way that is sensibly justified by its meaning(s) in standard English. We don't need a precise definition of a prefix, rather, just get your author to precisely define the specific instances of this prefix's use, e.g. "cocomplete" demands a precise definition, but the "co" does not.

Comment: It's **co**ntext-dependent.

Comment: The answer to this question shouldn't be "ncise".